# How can I access specific array in twig for symfony?

Tags: arrays, symfony, loops, twig

I have a problem, I only want to access a specific location of array,

Lets say I have this code

```
{% set total = val.listCompanies|length%}
  {% if total > 1 %}
    <td>
      <button id="viewcompany" 
          type="button" 
          class="pop btn btn-info" 
          data-toggle="popover" 
          title="User Company List" 
          data-content='
            {% for key1, val1 in val.listCompanies %}
              <a href ="company/{{val1.CompanyId}}"> {{ val1.CompanyName }}<br> </a>
            {% endfor %}'
          data-placement="right"
          data-html = "true">
        see company
      </button>
    </td>
  {% endif %}
  {% if total < 2 %}
    <td>
      {% for key1, val1 in val.listCompanies %}
        <center>
          <a href ="company/{{val1.CompanyId}}"> {{ val1.CompanyName }}<br> </a>
        </center>
      {% endfor %}
    </td>
  {% endif %}
```

I want to make a button, that if it contain only one array inside it, I dont have to use the popover button, but if it has more than 1 array inside of its, then I have to show it inside of the popover button.

The thing is I cant access the specific array, to add more logic..

Comment: What is the problem to access it?

Answer (score 0):

If your `val.listCompanies` contains numeric keys, you can access the first one by using:

```
val.listCompanies[0]
```

If your `val.listCompanies` has generated keys and you want to access the first one, you can use:

```
val.listCompanies|first
```

If your `val.listCompanies` has generated keys and you want to access the Nth one, you can use:

```
val.listCompanies|slice(n, 1)|first
```

#### [Working demo](http://twigfiddle.com/djkrej)